# Batch variable length sequences in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am reading variable length input sequences from files as numpy arrays, each of size `[timesteps_i, feature_size]`, and store them in a Python list.

Passing this list as argument to `tf.train.batch` results in a list of the same length, containing Tensors of size `[batch_size, timesteps_i, feature_size]`.

```
inputs_batch_padded = tf.train.batch(
                tensors=inputs_chunk,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                capacity=128,
                enqueue_many=False,
                dynamic_pad=True)
```

1. How can I obtain an output list that is `batch_size` times shorter than the original list?
2. How can it be inferred the original length of the sequences for each batch that is being passed to a `feed_dict`? I am checking out the seq to seq library, and it requires a list of lengths for each batch.
3. Am I supposed to pass numpy arrays for `tensors`? The `dynamic_pad` argument allows a `None` for the variable length dimension, but this will be known in advance in my case.
4. How should I interpret the following line from the API doc:
   "An input tensor with shape [x, y, z] will be output as a tensor with shape [batch_size, x, y, z]" ?
   Is the same input tensor being replicated `batch_size` times ?